# Ffmpeg output files not available immediately for use

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am executing split video Ffmpeg command on Android and it creates `output_%d` files to SD card (external storage)

Once command is executed and finished, files are not appearing immediately until I open Gallery App

I tried running media scanner for newly created directory but I see that directory is empty and has no files available immediately.

Comment: maybe you're not perform the media scanning correctly, seeing your code would be useful

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "not appearing immediately ?

**1/ With a file explorer ?**

This issue is due to the use of the MTP protocol. You have to do a rescan of the files using the MediaScannerConnection class.

Using a media scan app from google play help if you don't want to reboot or develop something.

**2/ from java ?**

You could try to list all files of the folder and then do a media scanner on each files (instead of doing it on the directory).

```
Context ctx = <your_context>;
File directory = new File("<your_path>");
File[] files = directory.listFiles();
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(files[i]));
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

If you need the result immediately when the scan is finished, you'll need MediaScannerConnectionClient

```
private static final class Client implements MediaScannerConnectionClient
{   private final String path;
    private final String mimeType;
    public MediaScannerConnection connection;

    public Client(String path, String mimeType)
    {   this.path = path;
        this.mimeType = mimeType;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMediaScannerConnected()
    {   connection.scanFile(path, mimeType);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri)
    {   connection.disconnect();
    }
};

public static void scanFile(Context context, String path, String mimeType)
{   Client client = new Client(path, mimeType);
    MediaScannerConnection connection = new MediaScannerConnection(context, client);
    client.connection = connection;
    connection.connect();
}
```

Ideally, this should be done in the ffmpeg splitter app.

Comment: Thanks Jerome. I did try `MediaScannerConnectionClient`
Here is what's happening 
- I execute Ffmpeg command to split video into multiple parts
- Once that command is successfully finished, I try to scan folder (path where splitted files should be saved)

However, problem is `File[] files = directory.listFiles();` is returning `null` and it seems output files are not ready/available immediately even after `Ffmpeg` command is finished.  

I will create sample gist for better explanation.

Comment: `Ffmpeg` is pure java library that's probably reason they aren't scanning it.

Comment: But then, after how long are they available?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

I am using this

You are using the Full sample Code Sample Here [record Video , Spilt image and take output l](https://github.com/sylvain-abadie/android-camera-recorder)

You try the command of FFmpeg as you want if you need any help let me know

```
public class FrontCameraPreviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraController.CameraRecordListener, FFMpegVideoGenerator.VideoGeneratorListener {
    public final static String TAG = "FrontCameraPreviewAct";

    private final static int CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 50;

    private FrontCameraSurfaceView mPreview;
    private FrameLayout mPreviewFrame;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    private Animation hideCameraFab;
    private CameraController mCameraController;
    private ProgressBar mPbProcessing;
    SweetAlertDialog progressDialog;
    int mCount;
    View mView;
    ImageView btn_record_image;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_front_camera_preview);
        mView=(View)findViewById(R.id.mView);
        btn_record_image=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_record_image);

        mView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_record);
        btn_record_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                btn_record_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                mCameraController.record();
                mCount=0;

                mView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(FrontCameraPreviewActivity.this,R.color.white));
                mView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                new CountDownTimer(Constants.VIDEO_DURATION, 100) {

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                        mCount++;

                        if(mCount%2 == 0)
                        {
                            mView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                        // mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                        //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
                    }

                    public void onFinish() {
                        mView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                }.start();



            }
        });



        progressDialog = new SweetAlertDialog(FrontCameraPreviewActivity.this, SweetAlertDialog.PROGRESS_TYPE);
        mPbProcessing = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb_processing);
        mPreviewFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fl_camera_preview);

        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        // Hide the status bar.
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN |
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        );


    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    this.initCamera();

                } else {
                    // TODO : display an error view
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED&&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);


        } else {
            initCamera();
        }
        super.onResume();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mCameraController != null) {
            mCameraController.release();
            mCameraController = null;
        }
    }

    private void initCamera() {
        if (mCameraController == null) {
            mCameraController = new CameraController(this);
            mCameraController.setCameraRecordListener(this);

            if (mCameraController.getCamera() == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.camera_not_available, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // TODO : display an error view
            } else if (mPreview == null) {
                mPreview = new FrontCameraSurfaceView(this, mCameraController.getCamera(), CameraController.getFrontCameraInfo());
                mPreviewFrame.addView(mPreview);
            } else {
                // handle the onResume after background properly
                mPreview.setCamera(mCameraController.getCamera());
            }
        } else {
            mCameraController.getCamera();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onCameraRecordSuccess(final File file) {
        this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                btn_record_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mCameraController.release();
                mPreviewFrame.removeAllViews();
                mCameraController = null;
                mPbProcessing.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                progressDialog.getProgressHelper().setBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(FrontCameraPreviewActivity.this, R.color.darkbutton));
                progressDialog.setTitleText("Processing...");
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                progressDialog.show();
            }
        });
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d(TAG, "start");
                FFMpegVideoGenerator generator = new FFMpegVideoGenerator(FrontCameraPreviewActivity.this.getApplication());
                generator.setVideoGeneratorListener(FrontCameraPreviewActivity.this);
                generator.convert(file);
            }
        }).start();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraRecordFailure() {
        this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(FrontCameraPreviewActivity.this, R.string.camera_not_available, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoGenerated(String message, File generatedFile) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        Intent intent = new Intent(FrontCameraPreviewActivity.this, VideoPreviewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(VideoPreviewActivity.VIDEO_PATH, generatedFile.getAbsolutePath());


        startActivity(intent);

        recreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoGeneratedError(String message) {
        Log.e(TAG, message);
    }
}
```

Split Images of Video and Other Functionality

**FFMpegVideoGenerator.java**

```
import android.content.Context;

import android.util.Log;

import com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler;
import com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpeg;
import com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.LoadBinaryResponseHandler;
import com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.exceptions.FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException;
import com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.exceptions.FFmpegNotSupportedException;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Locale;

import wc.arjs.boomerang.controllers.VideoGenerator;
import wc.arjs.boomerang.utils.FileUtils;
import wc.arjs.boomerang.Constants;


public class FFMpegVideoGenerator extends Thread implements VideoGenerator {

    private static final String TAG = "VideoGenerator";
    private static final String TEMP_IMG_DIR = "imgs";
    private static final String METADATA_PREFIX = "met_";
    private static final String CROP_PREFIX = "crop_";

    private WeakReference<VideoGeneratorListener> mWeakListener;

    private String mWorkingDir;
    private String mFinalOutputDir;
    private FFmpeg mFFmpeg;

    public FFMpegVideoGenerator(Context ctx) {
        mFFmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(ctx);
        mWorkingDir = ctx.getCacheDir() + File.separator + TMP_DIR;
        mFinalOutputDir = ctx.getCacheDir() + File.separator + OUTPUT_DIR;
    }

    @Override
    public void setVideoGeneratorListener(VideoGeneratorListener listener) {
        mWeakListener = new WeakReference<>(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void convert(final File inputFile) {
        FileUtils.createDirIfNeeded(mWorkingDir);
        FileUtils.createDirIfNeeded(mFinalOutputDir);

        try {
            mFFmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    fixMetaData(inputFile);
                }

            });
        } catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "not supported");
        }
    }


    private void fixMetaData(final File inputFile) {
        Log.d(TAG, "fixeMetaData");

        String c = "-y -i " + inputFile.getAbsolutePath() + " -metadata:s:v rotate=90 -codec copy "
                + mWorkingDir + File.separator + METADATA_PREFIX + inputFile.getName();

        String[] cmd = c.split(" ");
        try {
            mFFmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onFailure(String message) {
                    Log.e(TAG, message);
                    dispatchError(message);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String message) {
                    Log.d(TAG, message);
                    File generated = new File(mWorkingDir +
                            File.separator + METADATA_PREFIX + inputFile.getName());
                    cropVideo(generated);
                }

            });
        } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
            dispatchError(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void cropVideo(final File inputFile) {
        String c = "-y -i " + inputFile.getAbsolutePath() + " -vf crop=" +
                Constants.VIDEO_ASPECT_RATIO + "*in_h:in_h -preset ultrafast " +
                mWorkingDir + File.separator + CROP_PREFIX + inputFile.getName();

        String[] cmd = c.split(" ");
        try {
            mFFmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onFailure(String message) {
                    Log.e(TAG, message);
                    dispatchError(message);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String message) {
                    Log.d(TAG, message);
                    File generated = new File(mWorkingDir +
                            File.separator + CROP_PREFIX + inputFile.getName());
                    splitIntoImages(generated);
                }

            });
        } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
            dispatchError(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void splitIntoImages(final File inputFile) {
        Log.d(TAG, "splitIntoImages");

        final File tempImgsDir = new File(mWorkingDir + File.separator + TEMP_IMG_DIR);

        if (tempImgsDir.exists()) {
            FileUtils.deleteDirectory(tempImgsDir);
        }
        tempImgsDir.mkdir();

        String c = "-y -i " + inputFile.getAbsolutePath() +
                " -strict experimental -r 30 -qscale 1 -f image2 -vcodec mjpeg " +
                tempImgsDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "%03d.jpg";

        String[] cmd = c.split(" ");
        try {
            mFFmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onFailure(String message) {
                    Log.e(TAG, message);
                    dispatchError(message);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String message) {
                    Log.d(TAG, message);
                    reverseImagesOrder(tempImgsDir);
                    assembleVideo(tempImgsDir);
                }

            });
        } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
            dispatchError(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void reverseImagesOrder(final File inputDirectory) {
        File[] files = inputDirectory.listFiles();
        Arrays.sort(files);
        int nbImages = files.length;
        if (nbImages <= 2) {
            dispatchError("Not enough images generated");
        }
        // start from before the last image and duplicate all the images in reverse order
        for (int i = nbImages - 2; i > 0; i--) {
            File img = files[i];
            if (img.exists()) {
                String copiedImg = inputDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator +
                        String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%03d", 2 * nbImages - i - 1) + ".jpg";
                Log.d(TAG, copiedImg);
                FileUtils.copyAndRenameInDirectory(img.getAbsolutePath(), copiedImg);
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "file not found : " + img.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }

    private void assembleVideo(final File inputDirectory) {
        Log.d(TAG, "assembleVideo");
        File containingFolder = new File(mFinalOutputDir);

        final File assembledVideo = new File(containingFolder.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + FINAL_VIDEO_NAME);

        String[] cmdCreateMP4 = {
                "-framerate",
                "6",
                "-i",
                inputDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator +
                        "%03d.jpg",
                "-c:v",
                "libx264",
                "-profile:v",
                "high",
                "-crf",
                "20",
                "-pix_fmt",
                "yuv420p",
                assembledVideo.getAbsolutePath()};

        String c = "-framerate 70 -y -f image2 -loop 1 -i " + inputDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator +
                "%03d.jpg -r 30 -vcodec mpeg4 -b:v 2100k -t 4 " +
                assembledVideo.getAbsolutePath();

        String[] cmd = c.split(" ");
        try {
            mFFmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onFailure(String message) {
                    Log.e(TAG, message);
                    dispatchError(message);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String message) {
                    Log.d(TAG, message);
                   dispatchSuccess(message, assembledVideo);

                    /*String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                    File myDir = new File(root + "/boomerang/unsafe");
                    myDir.mkdirs();




                    String fname = "VID_"+ System.currentTimeMillis() +".mp4";
                    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
                    if (file.exists ())
                        file.delete ();
                    try {
                        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(assembledVideo.getAbsolutePath());
                        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

                        // Copy the bits from instream to outstream
                        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                        int len;
                        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                            out.write(buf, 0, len);
                        }
                        in.close();
                        out.close();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    File myDir1 = new File(root + "/boomerang/");





                    String fname1 = "VID_"+ System.currentTimeMillis() +".mp4";
                    File file1= new File (myDir1, fname1);
*/

                 //   concatenate(file.getAbsolutePath(),file.getAbsolutePath(),file1.getAbsolutePath());


                }

            });
        } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
            dispatchError(e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    private static String generateList(String[] inputs) {
        File list;
        Writer writer = null;
        try {
            list = File.createTempFile("ffmpeg-list", ".txt");
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(list)));
            for (String input: inputs) {
                writer.write("file '" + input + "'\n");
                Log.d(TAG, "Writing to list file: file '" + input + "'");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "/";
        } finally {
            try {
                if (writer != null)
                    writer.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Wrote list file to " + list.getAbsolutePath());
        return list.getAbsolutePath();
    }
    public void concatenate(String inputFile1, String inputFile2, final String outputFile) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Concatenating " + inputFile1 + " and " + inputFile2 + " to " + outputFile);
        String list = generateList(new String[] {inputFile1, inputFile2});

       /* String c = "ffmpeg -i "+inputFile1+" -qscale:v 1 intermediate1.mpg ffmpeg -i "+inputFile2+" -qscale:v 1 intermediate2.mpg cat intermediate1.mpg intermediate2.mpg > intermediate_all.mpg ffmpeg -i intermediate_all.mpg -qscale:v 2 "+
                outputFile;
*/


      /*  new String[] {
                "ffmpeg",
                "-f",
                "concat",
                "-i",
                list,
                "-c",
                "copy",
                outputFile
        }*/

        String c = "ffmpeg -i "+inputFile1+" -filter_complex [0]reverse[r];[0][r]concat,loop=5:250,setpts=N/25/TB " +
                outputFile;

        String[] cmd = c.split(" ");

        try {
            mFFmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onFailure(String message) {
                    Log.e(TAG, message);
                    //dispatchError(message);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String message) {
                    Log.d("@Success", "Ho gaya");
                    dispatchSuccess(message, new File(outputFile));



                }

            });
        } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
            //dispatchError(e.getMessage());
        }

/*

        Videokit vk = new Videokit();
        vk.run(new String[] {
                "ffmpeg",
                "-f",
                "concat",
                "-i",
                list,
                "-c",
                "copy",
                outputFile
        });
*/


    }

    private void dispatchSuccess(String message, File file) {
        if (mWeakListener != null && mWeakListener.get() != null) {
            mWeakListener.get().onVideoGenerated(message, file);
        }
    }

    private void dispatchError(String message) {
        if (mWeakListener != null && mWeakListener.get() != null) {
            mWeakListener.get().onVideoGeneratedError(message);
        }
    }
}
```

You can take the split image on this path which is cache temporary (android/data/....) save you change the path also as you want, makedirs and save the images in which you want to save

```
tempImgsDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "%03d.jpg"
```

**Cameracontroller**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.media.CamcorderProfile;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.FileObserver;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import wc.arjs.boomerang.Constants;

/**
 * Created by Sylvain on 26/11/2016.
 */

public class CameraController {
    private final static String TAG = "CameraController";


    public interface CameraRecordListener {
        void onCameraRecordSuccess(File file);
        void onCameraRecordFailure();
    }

    private CameraRecordListener mCameraRecordListener;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
    private boolean isRecording;
    private Context mContext;

    private static Camera GetFrontCameraInstance() {
        Camera c = null;
        int cameraId = GetFrontCameraId();
        try {
            c = Camera.open(cameraId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }

    private static int GetFrontCameraId() {
        Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        int count = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
            if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static Camera.CameraInfo getFrontCameraInfo(){
        Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        int count = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
            if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                return info;
            }
        }
        return info;
    }

    public CameraController(Context ctx){
        this.mContext = ctx;
        mCamera = GetFrontCameraInstance();

        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
      /*  params.setExposureCompensation(params.getMaxExposureCompensation());

        if(params.isAutoExposureLockSupported()) {
            params.setAutoExposureLock(false);
        }*/

        params.setRecordingHint(true);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
        isRecording = false;
    }

    public void setCameraRecordListener(CameraRecordListener cameraRecordListener){
        this.mCameraRecordListener = cameraRecordListener;
    }

    class RecordedFileObserver extends FileObserver {
        private File output;
        public RecordedFileObserver(File output, int mask) {
            super(output.getAbsolutePath(), mask);
            this.output  = output;
        }

        public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
            if(event == FileObserver.CLOSE_WRITE){
             if(mCameraRecordListener!=null){
                 mCameraRecordListener.onCameraRecordSuccess(output);
             }
            }
        }
    }

    public void record(){

        final File output = getOutputMediaFile();
        if (prepareVideoRecorder(output)) {
            // Camera is available and unlocked, MediaRecorder is prepared,
            // now you can start recording
            mMediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener(new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
                    if(what==MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED){
                        if (isRecording) {

                            RecordedFileObserver fb = new RecordedFileObserver(output, FileObserver.CLOSE_WRITE);
                            fb.startWatching();

                            // stop recording and release camera
                            mMediaRecorder.stop();  // stop the recording
                            releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
                            mCamera.lock();         // take camera access back from MediaRecorder
                            isRecording = false;
                        }
                    }else{
                        if(mCameraRecordListener!=null){
                            mCameraRecordListener.onCameraRecordFailure();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            mMediaRecorder.start();
            isRecording = true;

        } else {
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            if(mCameraRecordListener!=null){
                mCameraRecordListener.onCameraRecordFailure();
            }
        }

    }

    public void release(){
        this.releaseMediaRecorder();
        this.releaseCamera();
    }

    private boolean prepareVideoRecorder(File output) {

        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        // store the quality profile required
        CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CameraController.GetFrontCameraId(), CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P);

        // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
        mCamera.unlock();
        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
        // Step 2: Set sources
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(profile.fileFormat);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(profile.videoCodec);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(profile.videoBitRate);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(profile.videoFrameRate);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(profile.videoFrameWidth, profile.videoFrameHeight);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(640, 480);
       // recorder.setVideoSize(640, 480);
       // recorder.setVideoFrameRate(16); //might be auto-determined due to lighting
       // recorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(3000000);
       // recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);// MPEG_4_SP
      //  recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);


        // Step 4: Set output file
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(output.toString());
        // Set the duration
        mMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(Constants.VIDEO_DURATION);

        // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
        try {
            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void releaseCamera() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    private void releaseMediaRecorder() {
        if (mMediaRecorder != null) {
            mMediaRecorder.reset();   // clear recorder configuration
            mMediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
            mMediaRecorder = null;
            mCamera.lock();           // lock camera for later use
        }
    }

    private File getOutputMediaFile() {
        return new File(mContext.getFilesDir().getPath() + File.separator + Constants.VIDEO_TEMP_NAME);
    }


    public Camera getCamera() {
        return mCamera;
    }
}
```

**Constants**take

public class Constants {

```
public final static double VIDEO_ASPECT_RATIO = 0.6; // 1:5
public final static int VIDEO_DURATION = 2000;
public final static String VIDEO_TEMP_NAME = "VID_TEMP.mp4";
```

}